# An identity involving the determinant of a $N\times N$ matrix constructed from N numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, induction, determinant

Given a set of $D$ complex numbers $\{x_1,\dots x_D\}$ such that  $x_ix_j\neq 1$ for $i,j\in (1,\dots, D)$, construct a $D\times D$ matrix $Z$ whose matrix elements are given by $Z_{ij}=\frac{1-x^2_i}{1-x_ix_j}$.

Prove that
\begin{equation}
\det(Z)=\prod_{\substack{i,j=1\\ i>j}}^D\frac{(x_i-x_j)^2}{(1-x_ix_j)^2}. \label{eqdetZ}
\end{equation}

---

For example, when $D=2$,
\begin{equation}
\det(Z)=\det\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & \frac{1-x_1^2}{1-x_1x_2}\\
 \frac{1-x_2^2}{1-x_1x_2} &1
\end{matrix}\right)=\frac{(x_1-x_2)^2}{(1-x_1x_2)^2}
\end{equation}

---

An update: I think I have the proof. This identity can be written in terms of the Cauchy determinant Ref[1](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Value_of_Cauchy_Determinant)
\begin{equation}
\det\left(\begin{matrix}
\dfrac 1 {x_1 + y_1} & \dfrac 1 {x_1 + y_2} & \cdots & \dfrac 1 {x_1 + y_n} \\
\dfrac 1 {x_2 + y_1} & \dfrac 1 {x_2 + y_2} & \cdots & \dfrac 1 {x_2 + y_n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\dfrac 1 {x_n + y_1} & \dfrac 1 {x_n + y_2} & \cdots & \dfrac 1 {x_n + y_n} \\
\end{matrix}\right)= \dfrac {\displaystyle \prod_{1 \mathop \le i \mathop < j \mathop \le n} \left({x_j - x_i}\right) \left({y_j - y_i}\right)} {\displaystyle \prod_{1 \mathop \le i, \, j \mathop \le n} \left({x_i + y_j}\right)}
\end{equation}
once one replaces all $y_i$ by $-x_i^{-1}$.

Comment: Note that the diaginal entries are $1$. One easily sees that $\prod_{i\ne j}(1-x_ix_j)\cdot\det(Z)$ is a polynomial in the $x_i$. Can you determine its degree? See some obvious factors, i.e., some obvious conditions that make $\det(Z)=0$?

Comment: Cofactor expansion seems like it might be useful here.

Comment: Thank you guys for answering my question! I found that this identity can be written in terms of the Cauchy determinant in  https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Value_of_Cauchy_Determinant, once one replaces all y_i in the Cauchy determinant in the link by -x_i^{-1}.